# Converting Jy/beam to Jy?

Tags: radio-astronomy, units, interferometry

Maybe its a dumb question, but to convert Jy/beam to Jy, I just have to multiply it by the beam size in sr right?

Being $\Omega$ the beam size: 
$\Omega = \frac{\pi \theta_{maj} ~~ \theta_{min}}{4 \ln{2}}$

Jy/beam $\cdot \ \Omega$ = Jy   ?

Comment: Please add a little more info - define J and Jy, and what your beam source is -- for example is it a point source?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jansky

Answer (score 5):

Actually to convert from Jy/beam to Jy/pixel you need to divide by the beam size.

Let's say you have a quantity of 1 Jy/beam, then

$\frac{Jy}{beam} \frac{beam}{\Omega}$, then to go from Jy/beam to Jy/pixel you would need to divide by $\Omega$.

The values of the beam major and minor axis must be in pixels.

Source: [NRAO](https://science.nrao.edu/facilities/vla/proposing/TBconv)

Answer (score 3):

So long as you accurately know the beam size, then yes multiplying your Jy/beam measurement (effectively flux density) by the beam size (effectively area of flux) will give you the total Jy (effectively the flux).

[See this source as an example.](http://tsrice-research.blogspot.com/2016/05/how-to-manually-extract-flux-in-jy-from.html)

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you mean by "just Jy". Usually, what is meant is the surface brightness of a source, in some unit like $\operatorname{Jy}\operatorname{sr}^{-1}$ or $\operatorname{Jy}\operatorname{arcsec}^{-2}$, integrated over solid angle to get the source's total flux. What a measurement of $I \operatorname{Jy}\operatorname{beam}^{-1}$ is telling you is, roughly, "An unresolved source that is the nominal beam size with this peak flux will have total flux $I$ in Jy." So, if you want surface brightness, take your quantity in Jy/beam and divide by $\Omega$/beam (see the relationship between $S$ [flux] and $I$ [surface brightness] in [this brightness temperature NRAO tutorial](https://science.nrao.edu/facilities/vla/proposing/TBconv).

In most situations with radio astronomy, the clean beam will be a Gaussian, so
\begin{align}
   I &= I_{\text{Jy/beam}} \frac{\text{beam}}{\Omega_{\text{beam}}} \\
     &= I_{\text{Jy/beam}} \frac{1}{\pi \sigma_{\text{beam}}^2} \\
    &= I_{\text{Jy/beam}} \frac{4\ln(2)}{\pi \theta_{\text{beam}}^2},
\end{align}
with $\theta_{\text{beam}}$ the beams full width at half power and $\sigma_{\text{beam}}$ the standard deviation of the beam.

Once you have $I$, getting Jy / pixel is as easy as multiplying by $\Omega_{\text{pixel}}$. If you have some surface brightness profile you fit, like
\begin{align}
  I_{\text{model}} &= A \exp\left(-\frac{(x-x_0)^2\sigma_y^2- 2\rho\sigma_x\sigma_y(x-x_0)(y-y_0) + (y-y_0)^2}{2\sigma_x^2\sigma_y^2(1-\rho^2)}\right),
\end{align}
where $\sigma_x$ and $\sigma_y$ are normal standard deviations and $\rho$ is your normal correlation coefficient. For more normal astronomer usage, you'd use
\begin{align}
   \theta_M &= \sqrt{8\ln(2)\left[\frac{\sigma_x^2 + \sigma_y^2}{2} + \sqrt{\left(\frac{\sigma_x^2 - \sigma_y^2}{2}\right)^2 + \rho^2\sigma_x^2\sigma_y^2}\right]} \\
   \theta_m &=\sqrt{8\ln(2)\left[\frac{\sigma_x^2 + \sigma_y^2}{2} - \sqrt{\left(\frac{\sigma_x^2 - \sigma_y^2}{2}\right)^2 + \rho^2\sigma_x^2\sigma_y^2}\right]} \\
    \phi &= \left\{\begin{array}{ll}
        0 & \text{if }\rho=0,\ \sigma_y > \sigma_x \\
        90^\circ & \text{if }\rho=0,\ \sigma_x > \sigma_y \\
        \operatorname{atan2}\left(\theta_M^2 - 8\ln(2)\sigma_x^2, \sigma_y^2\right) & \text{otherwise}
    \end{array} \right.
\end{align}
Then you can convert the peak surface brightness $A$ to total brightness by integrating $I$ over all $x$ and $y$, yielding
\begin{align}
   S &= A 2\pi \sigma_x \sigma_y \sqrt{1-\rho^2} \\
     &= A \frac{\pi \theta_m \theta_M}{4\ln(2)}.
\end{align}

Note what happens if you combine the conversions from Jy/beam to surface brightness to Jy. You get:
\begin{align}
   S &= A \frac{\theta_m \theta_M}{\theta_{\mathrm{beam}}^2}.
\end{align}
C.f. Equation 35 of [Condon et al (1998)](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1998AJ....115.1693C). Note that Condon et al provide multiple equations that depend on how resolved thee source is. Based on the [referenced paper](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1997PASP..109..166C/abstract) it looks like what they're doing is minimizing the variance of their "corrected" values.