# How to convert Flux Density to Flux?

Tags: luminosity, units, flux

I have a radio catalogue with flux density values. (Jy/bm) I'm confused converting this value to flux. Because I want to calculate luminosity, I need flux values. The unit made me confused. Since I know the distance values converting flux to luminosity will be easy. I only need to convert flux density to flux

Comment: See this answer https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/26721/converting-jy-beam-to-jy#:~:text=Actually%20to%20convert%20from%20Jy,divide%20by%20the%20beam%20size.&text=Jybea,axis%20must%20be%20in%20pixels.

Answer (score 2):

The unit of Jansky (Jy) is a flux density, measured in 10^-26 W/m^2/Hz , which is a frequency specific quantity. In order to get the flux, you have to integrate the flux density over frequency bandwidth of the instrument.

See this link for more details and related quantities [https://www.mrao.cam.ac.uk/~kjbg1/lectures/lect1_1.pdf](https://www.mrao.cam.ac.uk/%7Ekjbg1/lectures/lect1_1.pdf)

Comment: I got my data from NRAO VLASS which is at 1.4ghz band. So how i can apply to this integral since there are only 1 frequency?